# IndexError: list index out of range from client side

Tags: python, python-2.7

Happy Friday. This puzzle is really a pain in my neck, any advice will be appreciated. Thanks a ton.

I am on Python 2.7 with Windows 7.
I send a piece of command to device via model-client model (im at client side) and wait for a response (charging status) from device. Then I would like to extract some value from the list of return. And BANG! Error pops out! "IndexError: list index out of range".

My Python code is in below:

```
    def chrg_Test():
        try:
            self.s.send(getchar)
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            print 'Chrg cmd sent failed...'
        print 'Start Chrg Test...'
        result = self.s.recv(1024)
        time.sleep(3)
        ExtPwrPresent = (result.split('\n'))[11]
        print 'ExtPwrPresent is: ', ExtPwrPresent
    chrg_Test()
```

And the Error is:

```
ExtPwrPresent = (result.split('\n'))[11]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Some other details: what is wired is , the error pops out like 50% or more. And rest time it works good. So it got some temper and on and off randomly which is like an annoying babe~ The correct output should be like:

```
Result list is: 
getchar 
Label,Value
FuelPercent,31
BatteryOverTemp,0
ChargingActive,0
ChargingEnabled,0
ConfidentOnFuel,0
OnReservedFuel,0
EmptyFuel,0
BatteryFailure,0
ExtPwrPresent,0
ThermistorPresent,1
BattTempCAvg,23
VBattV,14.42
VExtV,0.00
Charger_mAH,0
Discharge_mAH,200


ExtPwrPresent is:  ExtPwrPresent,0
```

So far, the solution I tried is - turn off the server socket and turn it on again, then run this client code. It works most time, but I think it is just a temporary way, I bet there is some better way to solve it.

Comment: What if `result.split('\n')` returns 5, 7, 2, or **even** 0 elements?

Comment: As you receive only 1024 bytes of data, what if there's more to come? How can you be so sure _all the data_ is received?

Comment: How are you sure that the index actually exists?

Comment: @ForceBru That is a good question, I've had the same thought. As I do can receive the full return (50% or less tho), can we believe 1024 bytes is enough?

Comment: @ZdaR Hi ZdaR, I am sorry I dont quit follow you. You mean return 5th,7th,2nd lines? If so, could you please enlighten me why 5,7,2 please?

Comment: @DeA um...I am not sure if my assumption is sound, correct me if I am wrong: the reason I believe the index exist is I do receive the full return I expect sometimes. Could it prove the index exist~?

Comment: Try running the script and printing the entire list before asking it to print the index, that way you'll know how many elements are there in each run

Comment: You can add something like `try:` ... `except IndexError: print(result)` around the line that causes the error, so that it prints the full result in cases where the 11th line is not present. Then perhaps you can re-try receiving the data?

Comment: @DeA I tried out your advice and confirmed the type and length of the 'list/output'. It turns out it actually is a string, and the length of it is 294. So I guess recv(1024) is enough~?

Comment: Hi @Stuart, I want to thank you first cuz it works good with your suggestion! (But I dont know why...;*) Here is my modified code: def chrg_Test():
   try:
    self.s.send(cmdGC)
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'Start Chrg Test...'
    result = self.s.recv(1024)
    ExtPwrPresent = (result.split('\n'))[11]
    print 'ExtPwrPresent is: ', ExtPwrPresent
    ExtPwrPresent = int(ExtPwrPresent[-2])
    print 'ExtPwrPresent vale is: ', ExtPwrPresent
   except IndexError:
    print "Error happens."
  chrg_Test()  ________ I tried 5 times, no 'IndexError' pops out, but why~~~?

Comment: You can't paste long code in the comment... Your error is occurring because `result` sometimes has less than 11 lines. So you need to debug by first investigating what `result` contains when this is happening. `print "Error happens. result contains:", result` would allow you to see this.